# htaccess Rewrite path to subdomain except the Index Document

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following structure in my website and I need to redirect all the traffic to a subdomain

Structure:

```
domain.com/subdomain/
                 .../folder1/folder/1.txt
                 .../folder1/folder/2.txt
                 .../folder2/folder/1.txt
                 .../folder2/folder/1.txt
                 .../index.php
```

I want to redirect all the traffic except the index.php or (domain.com/subdomain/) to a subdomain

Example:

```
domain.com/subdomain/folder1/folder/1.txt    --->    subdomain.domain.com/folder1/folder/1.txt
domain.com/subdomain/folder1/folder/2.txt    --->    subdomain.domain.com/folder1/folder/1.txt
```

But

```
domain.com/subdomain/index.php    --->    No redirect
domain.com/subdomain/    --->    No redirect
```

This is what I came up with:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [NC]
```

This works for all the request but I want to exclude both / & index.php from this RewriteRule

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a bit more than you have there. You must first check the domain with `RewriteCond`.  The pattern `^subdomain/?(index\.php)?$` should match requests to the subdomain root or `index.php` with or without `/`.  Technically it would also match the invalid `subdomainindex.php` without a `/` between but that would result in a 404 anyway.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the requested domain isn't already the subdomain...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\. [NC]
# Rewrite it to the subdomain
# unless it is a request for index.php or /
RewriteRule ^subdomain/?(index\.php)?$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*) http://subdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```